# Как превратить => === в один символ в vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Всем привет!
Подскажите как правильно это называется и можно ли использовать в VS Code:
Когда мы пишем => или ===, web-storm превращает это в один красивый символ, вопрос - можно как то это сделать в VS Code'е не меняя тему?

Или как это правильно называется.

Comment: Это называется «лигатуры».

Comment: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/VS-Code-Instructions

Comment: никогда не использовал, но интересно, не начинаешь путаться в символах? насколько я понимаю речь идет о `javascript`. Насколько удобно читать код? или это просто дело привычки

Comment: когда очень много стрелчных функций - мне это помогает ориентироваться лучше

Comment: @Dmitry не обязательно JS.  https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/

Comment: @AlexeyTen я и не спорю, предположил. И угадал

Comment: По запросу "font programming ligature" можно найти несколько шрифтов.